# Thank you for your availability

Tags: meaning, sentence-usage

Sometimes I find myself starting or ending emails with a "thank you" note to appreciate the person on the other side making available in case I need some help. His email may end with something like "Should you need any help, please don't hesitate to contact me".

In my native language we usually write "thank you for your availability". This translation sounds a bit weird to me, and I generally opt for something like "thank you for being so helpful", but the meaning is slightly different because it implies that the person has already helped me in some tangible way.

Is there a sentence commonly used in English to say "thank you for making you available to help should I need it"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't think of a commonly used sentence that would convey this meaning, but there's nothing wrong with writing, "Thank you for being available" or "Thank you for making yourself available."

We do sometimes thank people in advance and sometimes we note that the thanks is given in advance: "Thanks in advance for your help."

Comment: Or: "Thank you for staying in touch"